# Проблема Установка Явы

Tags: java

Что надо сделать,чтоб не вылетал баннер с такой надписью?

> Error: could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.
>
> Ошибка: не удалось найти среды выполнения Java SE.

Может в самой яве, в настройках, нужно снять где-то галочку?

Comment: java и javascript - это две абсолютно разные вещи. разница примерно как между кофе и Коффи Аннан.

Comment: попродробней раской проблему.

Comment: А переустановить JRE пробовали?

Answer (score 4):

Насколько я понял вопрос, в браузере не отображается Java аплет?

Для отображения аплетов **не нужен JDK** (он нужен для разработки приложений), соответственно не нужны никакие переменные среды типа PATH и JAVA_HOME.

1. Нужно скачать с **официального сайта** и установить последнюю версию **JRE**

   http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html
2. После установки JRE апплеты должны запускаться в IE и Firefox без проблем. (если этого не происходит - значит JRE установлена неправильно)
   в хроме, начиная с версии 42 по умолчанию отключен NPAPI, чтобы его включить переходим на вкладку `chrome://flags/#enable-npapi` И под пунктом **Включить NPAPI** нажимаем **Включить**. После перезагрузки браузера все должно заработать.